# Dynamic Excel columns and rows to SQL

Tags: c#, sql, excel, vba

I have an Excel template which has dynamic rows and columns (it means the Excel template will be downloaded based on the parameters I select in my UI). Now there will be some data in the Excel sheet against those dynamic rows and columns coming from the database. I want to modify that Excel and import it so that only the updated(modified) cell values are updated in database. I thought a lot and I think this can be done with macros (by changing the color of cells with updated values and picking them up from C#). I would welcome any other thoughts/approaches for this.

Comment: What method are you using to import this back into the database?

Comment: looping through excel via c#. is there any other method this can be done?

Comment: If this spreadsheet is Office 2007+, you could enable "track changes" and then iterate the list of changes programmatically using the .NET DocumentFormat.OpenXML library.

Comment: Thanks laylarenee..And yes the spreadsheet is office 2010. this sounds like a brilliant approach. but will i able to get the column headers and row headers programatically against which those cells are changed?(just to update them in database against the correct IDs)

Comment: Also can we enable the track changes feature of excel programmatically through C#?

Comment: For example, once you know that cell B6's value has changed, you could access the ID value from that row & the header information from that column.

Comment: Yes, this can be enabled programmatically. The [Revisions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.spreadsheet.revisions%28v=office.14%29.aspx) class has information about changes made.

Comment: thanks a lot Laylarenee

Answer (score 0):

An approach I have used is to create a webdav/REST service which can then be mounted as a drive in Windows.

The exposed file on the webdav service was simply a CSV, which users could edit in Excel, but the GET request was serviced by reading the database.

After making the changes, the user saved in Excel, which caused a PUT on the webdav service. The PUT request wrote the new values to the database.